# Enable scroll bars once a flow control exceeds a certain size in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize, autoscroll

I did some browsing and could not find an answered question that addresses this issue.

My winform consists of a fill-docked flow control with a bunch of other controls in it. More controls leave and are added during runtime, so I have the flowcontrol (and the winform) autosize to fit everything as it appears.

The issue is, I want scrollbars to appear once the form exceeds a certain size. So if the form is small, it continues to autosize to fit, but once it gets about a certain height, the internal flowcontrol keeps doing its thing but the form stops growing and a scroll bar appears.

Is there a way to do this? All combinations of dock, autoscroll, and autosize that I tried were fruitless, but maybe I was doing it wrong.

Just a quick note - currently, once the flowcontrol grows to be taller than the screen, it moves everything below that line over to a new column. I would also like to disable this, so that it continues to grow vertically regardless of screen height (because I will have scroll bars).

Comment: You'll need to set the form's MaximumSize property.  Top-level windows that grow themselves are not very good UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `FlowLayoutPanel` into a panel `panel1`

```
panel1.AutoScroll = true;
panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; //if you want

FlowLayoutControl.AutoSize = true;
FlowLayoutControl.AutoScroll = false;
FlowLayoutControl.Dock = DockStyle.None;
FlowLayoutControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
FlowLayoutControl.Location = new Point(0,0);
FlowLayoutControl.Size = new Size(FlowLayoutControl.Width, 0);
```

Comment: This worked most of the way. I also had to set form MaximumSize to prevent it from growing past the size of my screen, and had to set its initial size because otherwise I ended up with a strip. Both easy fixes and your solution got me most of the way there! Thanks! Although it seems silly I need to put a flowlayout panel inside a normal panel just to add functionality that the flowlayout already had properties for.

Comment: true, actually it's the same functionality if you just change `.AutoSize=false;` and `.AutoScroll=true;` which is easier. then you can dock it in your window and don't have to use another panel.

Comment: Not quite the same, because your first way means the whole window shrinks when there's only a few things in it, but then grows when things get added, up to a maximum size. Which is what I want, so yay!